# Using custom main loader with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, nasm

I wrote the following loader:

```
GLOBAL _start
EXTERN main

section .text

_start:
    xor     ebp, ebp        ;   ebp = 0
    pop     esi                 ; esi = argc
    mov     ecx, esp        ; ecx = argv

    and     esp, 0xFFFF ; align esp

    push    ecx ; load argv
    push    esi ; load argc
    call    main    ; call main

    push    eax     ; exit with main's ret value
    mov     ebx,0
    int     80h
```

And a short `main` function, now I'm trying to run compile and link these files using gcc, but using the commands

```
nasm -f elf32 loader.asm
gcc -c -m32 main.c
gcc -m32 main.o loader.o -o main.out
```

Results in a multiple definition of `_start` error. I imagine this is because gcc is trying to link his own `_start`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: with the gcc `-nostdlib` flag maybe ?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't told GCC to not link to the standard startup code, so GCC links to it.

To tell GCC to not link in `_start`, pass in the [`-nostartfiles`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-nostartfiles-1151) flag to GCC when linking.

Note that the standard libraries (stdlib, stdio, etc) will still be linked in, unless you also use the `-nodefaultlibs` flag. The `-nostdlib` flag combines the two.